# How can I change the ORDER BY clause depending on the parameters that are passed into the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-order-by, dynamic-sql

I am passing 3 parameters into my stored procedure: `@Time, @DeptID, @Value`.

1. `@Time` is representing: 1=past 24hours, 2=past week, 3=past month, 4=past year
2. `@DeptID` is the ID of the various departments
3. `@Value` 1=Sort by Low, 2=Sort by High

Here is my current code:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = ('SELECT S.ID, S.[Description], D.Department, S.Value, S.[Date] FROM Suggestions S INNER JOIN Department D ON D.ID = S.DeptID WHERE Approved =1')

IF (@DeptID = 0 AND @Value = 0 AND @Time = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = (@SQL +' ORDER BY [Date] DESC')
    END

IF (@Time > 0)
   BEGIN
    SET @SQL = (CASE WHEN @Time = 1 THEN (@SQL + ' AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) ORDER BY S.[Date] DESC')
             WHEN @Time = 2 THEN (@SQL + ' AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) ORDER BY S.[Date] DESC' )
             WHEN @Time = 3 THEN (@SQL + ' AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) ORDER BY S.[Date] DESC')
             WHEN @Time = 4 THEN (@SQL + ' AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE()) ORDER BY S.[Date] DESC') END)
   END

IF (@DeptID > 0)
   BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND S.DeptID = @DeptID ORDER BY S.[Date] DESC')
   END

IF (@Value > 0)
   BEGIN
    SET @SQL = (CASE WHEN @Value = 1 THEN (@SQL + ' ORDER BY S.Value DESC')
             WHEN @Value = 2 THEN (@SQL + ' ORDER BY S.Value ASC')
```

This is fine when only one parameter is passed in, but when trying to filter by two or more parameters then I run into a problem...
So far I have been getting errors because I am adding 2 'Order By' clause onto the end of my Statement:

```
ORDER BY S.[Date] DESC ORDER BY S.Value DESC
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?
Any help at all would be much appriciated

Comment: create a temp table to store the end result in it. then use `if else` or `switch` to execute queries depending on your parameter values. I can give further info if this is what you want to do.hope this helps

Comment: I think @Lamak code would be a better solution to what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I rewrote your code to not use dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT  S.ID, 
        S.[Description], 
        D.Department, 
        S.Value, 
        S.[Date] 
FROM Suggestions S 
INNER JOIN Department D 
    ON D.ID = S.DeptID 
WHERE Approved =1
AND (@Time = 0 
     OR (@Time = 1 AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
     OR (@Time = 2 AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()))
     OR (@Time = 3 AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE()))
    )
AND (@DeptID = 0
     OR (@DeptID > 0 AND S.DeptID = @DeptID)
    )
ORDER BY [Date] DESC,
         CASE WHEN @Value = 1 THEN S.Value
         ELSE 1 END DESC,
         CASE WHEN @Value = 2 THEN S.Value
         ELSE 1 END ASC
```

**Updated with dynamic SQL version**

Ok, if you want the dynamic SQL solution, then this is one way (but first, did you read [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html%E2%80%8E)?):

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX), @WHERE VARCHAR(MAX), @ORDER VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = ('SELECT S.ID, S.[Description], D.Department, S.Value, S.[Date] FROM Suggestions S INNER JOIN Department D ON D.ID = S.DeptID WHERE Approved =1')

SET @WHERE = ' AND ' + 
             CASE WHEN @Time = 0 THEN '1 = 1'
             WHEN @Time = 1 THEN '[Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())'
             WHEN @Time = 2 THEN '[Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())'
             WHEN @Time = 3 THEN '[Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())'
             WHEN @Time = 4 THEN '[Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE())' END

SET @WHERE = @WHERE + 
             CASE WHEN @DeptID > 0 THEN ' AND S.DeptID = @DeptID'
             ELSE '' END

SET @ORDER = ' ORDER BY S.[Date] DESC' + 
             CASE WHEN @Value = 0 THEN ''
             WHEN @Value = 1 THEN ', S.Value DESC'           
             WHEN @Value = 2 THEN ', S.Value ASC' END

SET @SQL = @SQL + @WHERE + @ORDER

PRINT @SQL
```

Comment: Thanks Lamak, the only problem with this is that the code I posted is a condensed version of my actual stored procedure. So I need it to be dynamic or it might end up being quite a long cumbersome piece of code

Comment: +1 but keep in mind that in a lot of cases you might be better off with the dynamic SQL version, since the ORDER can definitely impact the chosen plan, and the chosen plan might not be efficient for all variations of the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I agree with all of your dynamic SQL but why not just check if the order by clause is already in the SQL String and if it is just add the additional parameter otherwise add the entire clause. You can do this using CharIndex.

I would also suggest only adding the DESC at the very end just before you execute the @SQL

```
IF (@DeptID = 0 AND @Value = 0 AND @Time = 0)
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX('ORDER BY',@SQL) = 0
    BEGIN
      SET @SQL = (@SQL +' ORDER BY [Date] ')
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @SQL = (@SQL +',[Date] ')
    END
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' DESC'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Armitage, CHARINDEX() was helpful.

Comment: I tried to vote up your answer but I do not have enough reputation yet, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE datetime = CASE @Time 
                    WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())
                    WHEN 2 THEN DATEADD(ww, -1, GETDATE())
                    WHEN 3 THEN DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE())
                    WHEN 4 THEN DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())
                END

SELECT  S.ID, 
        S.[Description], 
        D.Department, 
        S.Value, 
        S.[Date] 
FROM    Suggestions S INNER JOIN Department D ON D.ID = S.DeptID 
WHERE   Approved = 1 AND
        (S.DeptID = @DeptId OR @DeptID = 0) AND
        [DATEADD] >= @STARTDATE
ORDER BY case @Value when 0 then [Date] else 0 end,
        case @Value when 1 then S.Value else S.Value * -1 end
```

Comment: Please don't use lazy shorthands like `dd` and `ww`. If you mean `DAY`, then type `DAY`. Why shouldn't you use shorthands? Let me know if you guess the correct results for both of these values (and please quiz your colleagues, too): `SELECT DATEADD(Y, 1, GETDATE()), DATEPART(W, GETDATE());` Much better to be explicit and completely unambiguous. Also see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx

Comment: I don't think those 'lazy' shorthands are ambiguous, and I'd rather see `DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())` than `DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE())` .

Comment: You don't think `Y` is ambiguous? Did you try it? Did it return the result you expect? Also I wasn't suggesting the replacement you suggested (which wouldn't work in a leap year). I suggested simply changing `YY` to `YEAR`. What advantage do you get for using `YY` instead of `YEAR`? Saving two keystrokes? At what cost? It's about readability and promoting best practices. You may have memorized all of the shorthands and know which ones are misleading, but not all of your readers have.

Comment: Hopefully my readers just see four `DATEADD` statements in a row and assume that `dd, ww, mm, yy` refer to days, weeks, months and years without giving it too much thought. I agree that `W/WW` and `Y/YY` could be disasters waiting to happen in a different context, but here, as read, I think it's pretty clear whats going on.

Comment: I think you're failing to see the bigger picture, and inexplicably ignoring my question: what do you ***gain*** by being terse and ambiguous? Remember that when you post a "solution" on the Internet, other users may learn from it... in this case bad habits. It's not just about what you're presenting in the context of this specific question. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the criteria for your last two if statements are being met and you're adding your order clause twice.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = ('SELECT S.ID, S.[Description], D.Department, S.Value, S.[Date] FROM Suggestions S INNER JOIN Department D ON D.ID = S.DeptID WHERE Approved =1')

IF (@DeptID = 0 AND @Value = 0 AND @Time = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = (@SQL +' ORDER BY [Date] DESC')
    END

IF (@Time > 0)
   BEGIN
    SET @SQL = (CASE WHEN @Time = 1 THEN (@SQL + ' AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) ORDER BY S.[Date] DESC')
             WHEN @Time = 2 THEN (@SQL + ' AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())' )
             WHEN @Time = 3 THEN (@SQL + ' AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())')
             WHEN @Time = 4 THEN (@SQL + ' AND [Date] >= DATEADD(DAY, -365,GETDATE())') END)
   END

IF (@DeptID > 0)
   BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND S.DeptID = @DeptID')
   END

IF (@Value > 0)
   BEGIN
    SET @SQL = (CASE WHEN @Value = 1 THEN (@SQL + '  ORDER BY S.[Date] DESC, S.Value DESC')
             WHEN @Value = 2 THEN (@SQL + ' ORDER BY S.[Date] ASC, S.Value ASC')
```

Comment: I scrolled over and saw the order clauses in the first 'IF' statement too. I edited to code I pasted to take them out.